Orbital correlation diagram of cylobutane opening to ethylene
In one of the previous exams, we were asked to draw the orbital correlation diagram for the ring-opening of cyclobutane to two molecules of ethylene. The first step would be to draw the transition state, in order to denote which molecular orbitals are symmetric or antisymmetric to the transition state. The overall reaction should be thermally forbidden if I recall correctly, because it is the reverse reaction of a 2+2 cycloaddition.
Drawing the MO’a for ethylene is easy enough, but which MO’s does cyclobutane consist and which do I need to take into account? I am in a bit of a loss here.
The transition state should be a structure like this (Instead of the oxygens, there should be methylene groups.)

